# Best practices for handling HTTP 404 responses in Rails using Turbo Frames?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo, hotwire

I'm thinking through how Turbo Streams work, mostly as a thought experiment.  I understand the basics after building a simple toy application.  It's pretty powerful that so much can be done with a handful of Turbo Frames.

It's interesting to be able to respond with a Turbo Frame and the right content is replaced in the DOM.  However, I've noticed that if a link within a Turbo Frame responds with HTTP 404, it only shows up in the error console.  (Nothing changes on the visible page.)  What's the best practice for handling errors like these?  What's a simple option to give the user an indication that there's a broken link?

Comment: perhaps a tooltip popup (which point to the broken link)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [rescue_from](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) method in the controller that catches that specific error then use turbo_streams to update the page with a nice little error message

Comment: I don't think that's a very good solution because turbo streams are only supported on form submissions and subscribing to updates.

Comment: @BenjaminOakes this is incorrect. You can add turbo streams to literally any controller action / server response, not constrained to a form submission or model update.

Comment: Hmm, maybe a difference in how I'm using the terminology. In any case, can you please educate me on how that would best be used for a 404 response?  An example would be very helpful.